# Terminology for SQL Statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was curious if the sections of an SQL statement are given names.  Like you can have nouns, pronounds, predicates, etc. in the english language

For instance, how would each section be identified?

```
SELECT ID, PDATE, PDESC          <--- Query Type?
FROM TABLE_X                     <--- Predicate?
WHERE ID=4                       <--- Criteria?
ORDER BY ID DESC                 <--- ???
```

Thanks

Comment: Projection, predicate and ordering

Comment: select clause, from clause, where clause, order clause, santa clause.

Comment: I don't think that's something commonly used, as there are many possible SQL statements. You have inserts, updates, simple sets... For example, here they don't name them:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms190617.aspx
BTW, a predicate is an expression that evaluates to TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.

Comment: The FROM would be the subject if being compared to English. The where clause is commonly considered to contain predicates, same as join conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parts of SQL `SELECT` are called [*clauses*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql). According to Microsoft Documentation,

- `SELECT` is followed by *select list*,
- `FROM` is followed by *table source*,
- `WHERE` and `HAVING` are followed by *search condition*,
- `GROUP BY` introduces a *group by clause*,
- `ORDER BY` is followed by an *order by expression*.

Comment: Thanks.  this is what i was looking for, exactly.  Thanks all who answered.

Comment: It's almost like A is called A, B is called B, . . . :)

Comment: @GurV That's 100% true for the last two items, because they introduce concepts specific to SQL language.